# Is there any way to directly deal with wcf web.config via powershell?

Tags: wcf, powershell, powershell-2.0

We are having many wcf web.config files and to do configuration we are treating these files as xml and doing changes via powershell.

Is there any alternate way is there? Whether any direct way there from powershell like doing binding adding httpEnabled=true kind of operation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the easiest way to deal with the config file as xml like `$config = [xml](get-content "web.config")`. The are classes like [BasicHttpBindingElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.basichttpbindingelement(v=vs.110).aspx) which have methods to serialize and deserialize their data.

Actually you have access to all configuration classes in the [System.ServiceModel.Configuration Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.Configuration(v=vs.110).aspx).